# $d(p,q)=1$ if $p\ne q$, $0$ if $p=q$. What are the compact sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is an exercise of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (Ch2).  Let $X$ be an infinite set with the following metric:
$$d(p,q)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1, \quad p\ne q\\0, \quad p=q\end{array}\right.$$
I'm not sure if I have answered the following questions correctly. (I put my answers in parentheses.)  Can someone please confirm or correct me if I'm wrong?
Thanks a lot!

(1) Which subsets of $X$ are open?  $\quad$(any subset of $X$)
(2) Which are closed?  $\quad$(any subset of $X$)
(3) Which are compact?  $\quad$(only *finite* subsets of $X$)

The key argument of my proof is that for any $x\in X$, any neighborhood of $x$ of radius $r<1$ contains only $x$, i.e. $\forall r<1, N_r(x)=\{x\}.$  From this fact, I obtained answers to (1) and (2) quite readily.  For (3), any infinite subset $A$ of $X$ can be written as: 
$$A=\underset{x\in A}\cup\{x\},$$
which is an open cover of $A$, since each $\{x\}$ is open in $X$.  This open cover cannot have a finite subcover (because it would contain only finite points.)  So it appears that only finite subsets can be compact.

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your answers are correct.  Also clearly written.

In general, every finite subset of every topological space is compact, and this example (called the *discrete topology*, and $d$ is sometimes called the *discrete metric*) shows that this is the most we can say without some further condition, since there may not be any other compact subsets.

The opposite example is that in a space with the trivial topology, every subset is compact.